# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away after "Run import"

Tags: database, importexport, magmi

we are using magmi_full_0.7.19a

we tried "Run Import" , we are getting following error.

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away -
```

[image]

is it related to server issue . how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In magento when you will get `MySQL server has gone away` that mean magento is unable to connect with your mysql server host.  So check what happening on your server ..

Comment: but in site, i never faced this issue in admin panel or in frontend, it happened only in magmi page when i click on "run import"

Comment: caz magmi is putting much load on your server. And server is not able to take that load and he started refusing connection

Comment: we placed a csv file under var/import directory.

but still we are getting mesage as : No csv files found in magmi page : http://prnt.sc/av0i67